# Pandas does not plot if label includes Turkish Characters like ş,ö,ü

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

My problem, I can't plot when label include turkish characters like ş,ö,ü,İ,Ğ,ğ

it just gives this output --> matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f8499386050   not show the graph

How can I fix it?

here is my code:

```
def draw_pie(year,y,by):

    v=data[data['yil']==year]

    v=v.sort(y,ascending=False).head(20)

    v=v.groupby(by).aggregate('sum')

    veri= v[ y ]

    veri.plot(figsize=(10,10),kind='pie', labels=v.index,
               autopct='%.2f', fontsize=20)
    plt.show()

    draw_pie(2014,'toplam_hasilat','tur')
```

don't show beacuse tur contains 'Aşk' , 'Gençlik'

it is okay without turkish characters.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you decide to use universal encoding:

You first have to tell the source encoding is utf-8 (first line below). Then you have to decode the string as utf-8. If python3 it should work, if python2 you can tell it to behave like python3:

Example (Python 2.7.8)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
plt.title("Simple Plot şöüİĞğ")
plt.show()
```

You can also explicitely decode each string but that might not be very convenient (two solutions below)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
plt.title("Simple Plot şöüİĞğ".decode('utf-8'))
plt.xlabel(u"Simple Plot şöüİĞğ")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really  , I realized that too, it has other problems too. I can give point yet:(

Answer (score 0):

I've used the solution for my problem as follows.

I was trying to read data from Excel with Turkish fonts. Pandas failed in plotting the data in my Jupyter noteboook. Then I added

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

in the first cell, ran the all cells. Then I got my plots.